# how i can set my items to full screen of all device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

how i can set my items to full screen of all device,
i have RecyclerView and CardView for horizontal and vertical listview

singleitems.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_az"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_be"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_tripCondition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_tripCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_tripDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

main_items.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnMore"
        android:text="Sample title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="More" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and i use like this in my activity_main.xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.software.mahoo.operator.Activityes.Act_Request">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:gravity="right"/>
```

with this code my item is like this picture :

[image]

i want fit to all device fullscreen like this picture :

[image]

items is horizontal , and with swipe to right item change scroll to next item .
how i can do this ?

Comment: in listview vertical , i can't set custom size to height too . now in this listview(Horizontal) i can't set custom size to width . how i can do this ?

Comment: Is this possible?